# Por qué falla la llamada ajax desde el MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

una consulta, intento hacer una llamada a ajax desde mi mvc .net framework y no logro hacer que se cargue mi tabla de usuarios en mi index. no se que esta mal

**Esto No VA**
*(no me funciona mi proyecto, nunca hace la llamada a mi usuario.js no entiendo por que, tengo mi seecion de index, UsuarioController, ServicioUsuario y dao usuario, traigo mi modelo desde el dao, enservicio armo el modelo, lo paso a controller y en el index intento llamar a mi ajax y ni pasa por este no entiendo que tengo mal. por favor espero que alguien pueda darme una mano muchas gracias..)*

nesesito que se cargue la tabla y poder añadir al  menos, gracias

mi index

```
    @model Entidades.Models.ListaUsuariosModel
    
    
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "USUARIOs";
        List<SelectListItem> items = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.items;
    
    }
    <script src="~/Scripts/Usuario.js"></script> @*llamo a usuario .js*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
    <head>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Lista Usuarios</h2>
    
    
    
    
    
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="clearTextBox();">Agregar Usuario</button><br /><br />
        <table id="TablaUsuarios" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:100px" ;>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Rol</th>
    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    
    
                @foreach (var a in Model.Usuarios)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@a.Nombre</td>
                        <td>@a.Email</td>
                        <td>@a.RolUsuario</td>
                        <td>@a.IdUsuario</td>
    
    
    
                        <td style="text-align : center">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" id="btn_act" name="btn_act" onclick="location.href=''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> Actualizar </span></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="btn_eli" name="btn_act" onclick="location.href=''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Eliminar </span></button>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Modifica", "Modificar", new { id = a.IdUsuario })
    
    
                        </td>
    
                    </tr>
                }
    
    
    
    
    
            </tbody>
    
        </table>
    
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">agregar Usuario</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            @*ventana modal nuevo usuario*@
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Contrasena">Contraseña</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña" />
                            </div>
    
    
    
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.IdRol, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "IdRolUsuario", "NombreRol", Model.IdRol))
    
    
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd" onclick="return add();">Add</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnUpdate" style="display:none;" onclick="Update();">Update</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
    
    
    </body>
    
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
    loadData();
});


//Load Data function
function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Usurio/Listar",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + item.IdUsuario + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Nombre + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Email + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Contrasena + '</td>';
                /*             html += '<td>' + item. + '</td>';*/
                html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyID(' + item.IdUsuario + ')">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="Delele(' + item.IdUsuario + ')">Delete</a></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.tbody').html(html);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}


//add Data function  
function Add() {
    var res = validate();
    if (res == false) {
        return false;
    }
    var objUsuario = {
        /*IdUsuario: $('#IdUsuario').val(),*/
        Nombre: $('#Nombre').val(),
        Email: $('#Email').val(),
        Contrasena: $('#Contrasena').val()

    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Usuario/Crear",
        data: JSON.stringify(objUsuario),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            loadData();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}


    
    
    
    using Dapper;
    using Entidades.Entidades;
    using Servicios;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    
    namespace baseball2.Controllers
    {
        public class UsuarioController : Controller
        {
            private ServicioUsuario _servicioUsuario;
            public UsuarioController()
            {
                this._servicioUsuario = new ServicioUsuario();
            }
    
            // muestra la tabla de todos los usuarios
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
    
                var modelo = _servicioUsuario.BuscarUsuario();
                var modeloRol = _servicioUsuario.BuscarRoles();
    
                List<SelectListItem> items = modeloRol.Roles.ConvertAll(d =>
                {
                    return new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = d.NombreRol,
                        Value = d.IdRolUsuario.ToString(),
                        Selected = false,
                        
    
    
                    };
                });
                //mando la lista de items en el viewbag
                ViewBag.items = items;
    
    
                return View("Index", modelo);
            }
    
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult indexx()
            {
    
    
    
    
                return View();
            }
    
    
            //action para completar el DropDowlist 
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Crear()
            {
                var modeloRol = _servicioUsuario.BuscarRoles();
    
                List<SelectListItem> items = modeloRol.Roles.ConvertAll(d =>
                {
                    return new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = d.NombreRol,
                        Value = d.IdRolUsuario.ToString(),
                        Selected = false
    
    
                    };
                });
                //mando la lista de items en el viewbag
                ViewBag.items = items;
    
    
    
                return View();
    
            }
    
            // manda el modelo de usuario para hacer el insert en la BD
            [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult Crear(Usuario usuario)
            {
    
    
    
                //_servicioUsuario.InsertarUsuario(usuario);
    
                
    
                return Json(_servicioUsuario.InsertarUsuario(usuario), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    
            }
    
            //public ActionResult ObtenerIdRolJson()
            //{
            //    var modeloRol = _servicioUsuario.BuscarRoles();
    
            //    List<SelectListItem> items = modeloRol.Roles.ConvertAll(d =>
            //    {
            //        return new SelectListItem()
            //        {
            //            Text = d.NombreRol,
            //            Value = d.IdRolUsuario.ToString(),
            //            Selected = false
    
    
            //        };
            //    });
    
    
    
    
            //    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //}
    
    
    
            public ActionResult Delete(int id)
            {
                var param = new DynamicParameters();
                
                    return null;
            }
    
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Modificar(int? IdUsuario)
            {
               
    
                return View();
    
    
    
    
            }
    
            //[HttpPost]
            //public ActionResult Modificar(Usuario us)
            //{
            //    _servicioUsuario.ModificarUsuario(us);
            //    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    
    
    
            //}
    
            [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult Modificar(Usuario us)
            {
                try
                {
                    
                        _servicioUsuario.ModificarUsuario(us);
                    
                   
    
    
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        us
                    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
    
                    return Json(ex.Message);
                }
          
    
    
    
            }
    
    
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    using Dao.Daos;
    using Dao.Daos.Interfaces;
    using Entidades.Entidades;
    using Entidades.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    
    namespace Servicios
    {
        public class ServicioUsuario
        {
            private IUsuarioDao _usuarioDao;
            public ServicioUsuario()
            {
                this._usuarioDao = new UsuarioDao();
    
            }
    
            public ListaUsuariosModel BuscarUsuario()
            {
    
                ListaUsuariosModel listaus = new ListaUsuariosModel();
                var lista2 = new List<UsuarioModel>();
    
                var lista = _usuarioDao.Mostrar();
                for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
                {
                    UsuarioModel usuarioModel = new UsuarioModel();
                    usuarioModel.Email = lista[i].Email;
                    usuarioModel.Nombre = lista[i].Nombre;
                    usuarioModel.RolUsuario = lista[i].RolUsuario;
                    usuarioModel.IdUsuario = lista[i].IdUsuario;
                    // agrego Idrolus para mandar al dropdownlist
                    usuarioModel.IdRolUsuario = lista[i].IdRolUsuario;
                    //usuarioModel.IdRolUsuario = usuarioModel.IdRolUsuario;
    
    
                    lista2.Add(usuarioModel);
    
                }
                listaus.Usuarios = lista2;
    
                ListarRoles(listaus);
                return listaus;
    
            }
            //metodo para llenar el 
            public ListaRolesModel BuscarRoles()
            {
    
                ListaRolesModel listaus = new ListaRolesModel();
                var lista2 = new List<RolModel>();
    
                var lista = _usuarioDao.MostrarRoles();
                for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
                {
                    RolModel rolModel = new RolModel();
                    rolModel.IdRolUsuario = lista[i].IdRolUsuario;
                    rolModel.NombreRol = lista[i].NombreRol;
                    
    
    
    
                    lista2.Add(rolModel);
    
                }
                listaus.Roles = lista2;
    
    
                return listaus;
    
            }
    
            private  ListaUsuariosModel ListarRoles(ListaUsuariosModel model)
            {
    
               
                var lista2 = new List<RolModel>();
    
                var lista = _usuarioDao.MostrarRoles();
                for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
                {
                    RolModel rolModel = new RolModel();
                    rolModel.IdRolUsuario = lista[i].IdRolUsuario;
                    rolModel.NombreRol = lista[i].NombreRol;
    
    
    
    
                    lista2.Add(rolModel);
    
                }
                model.Roles = lista2;
    
    
                return model;
            }
                public Usuario InsertarUsuario(Usuario us)
            {
                UsuarioDao usuario = new UsuarioDao();
    
                usuario.Insertar(us);
                
                
    
    
                return us;
    
            }
    
            public Usuario ModificarUsuario(Usuario us)
            {
                UsuarioDao usuario = new UsuarioDao();
    
                usuario.Modificar(us);
    
    
    
    
                return us;
    
            }
    
    
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    using Dao.Daos.Interfaces;
    using Dao.Db;
    using Dapper;
    using Entidades.Entidades;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    
    namespace Dao.Daos
    {
        public class UsuarioDao : DaoDb, IUsuarioDao
    
        {
            DaoDb nuevodaodb = new DaoDb();
    
            private const string qrselectUsuarios = @"select Usuario.Nombre as Nombre, Usuario.Email as Email, RolUsuario.NombreRol as RolUsuario, RolUsuario.IdRolUsuario as IdRolUsuario, Usuario.IdUsuario  
                                                    FROM Usuario
                                                    INNER JOIN RolUsuario 
                                                    ON Usuario.IdRolUsuario = RolUsuario.IdRolUsuario
                                                    where Activo = 1";
    
    
            //Muestra el listado de todos los usuarios
            public List<Usuario> Mostrar()
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var con = AbrirConexion())
                    {
                        return con.Query<Usuario>(qrselectUsuarios).AsList();
    
    
                    }
    
                }
    
    
                catch (Exception)
                {
    
                    throw;
                }
    
    
    
            }
    
    
            //Mostrar Roles para el DropDownList
    
            private const string qrselectRoles = @"select * from RolUsuario";
    
            public List<RolUsuario> MostrarRoles()
            {
                try
                {
    
                    using (var con = AbrirConexion())
                    {
                        return con.Query<RolUsuario>(qrselectRoles).AsList();
    
                    }
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
    
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
            private const string qrInsertUsuarios = @"INSERT INTO Usuario(Nombre,Contrasena,Email,IdRolUsuario,Activo) 
                                                    Values(@nombre, @Contrasena, @email, @idRolUsuario,@activo) ";
    
            public bool Insertar(Usuario us)
            {
                try
    
                {
                    int result = 0;
                    using (var con = AbrirConexion())
                    {
    
                        result = con.Execute(qrInsertUsuarios, new { nombre = us.Nombre, contrasena = us.Contrasena,
                            email = us.Email, idRolUsuario = us.IdRolUsuario, activo = 1  });
                        return true;
                    }
    
    
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
    
    
                    throw ex;
                }
    
            }
    
    
            private const string qrDeleteUsuarios = @"SPBajaUsuario";
    
            public bool Eliminar(int Id)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var con = AbrirConexion())
                    {
                        con.Query<Usuario>(qrDeleteUsuarios, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                        //return con.Query<List<Usuario>>(selectUsuario);
                        return true;
                    }
    
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
    
    
                    throw;
                }
    
            }
    
    
    
    
            private const string qrModificarUsuarios = @"UPDATE Usuario SET Nombre = @Nombre,
                                                                               Contrasena = @Contrasena,
                                                                               Email = @Email 
                                                                               Where IdUsuario = @IdUsuario;";
            public bool Modificar(Usuario us)
            {
                try
                {
                    int result = 0;
                    using (var con = AbrirConexion())
                    {
    
                        result = con.Execute(qrModificarUsuarios, us);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
    
                    throw;
                }
    
            }
        }
      
    }
```

Comment: Sin spam te va mejor en la vida. Esa restricción está ahí para que hagas una mejor pregunta, no para impedírtelo. Por ejemplo, no sabemos si te sale algún error en algún log, en la consola del navegador, etc.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Hola Maxi, como te han mencionado sería bueno que comentes si estás teniendo algún error. Lo poco que puedo ver es que en el ajax usas url: "/Usurio/Listar" y en el controlador no encuentro ese "action"